# How to select top K items from 2 pandas DataFrame based on conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Assume, there are two DataFrame: **visitor** & **group**.
**visitor** stores each visitor information and which item s/he selected (likelihood values). However, not every item has been purchased by all visitors. **group** stores the certain items belong to which item-family information. The following are the toy DataFrames

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
items = [11,12,13,14, 
         21,22,23,24,
         2,7,9,10]
col_names = [2,7,9,10,11,13,14,21,24]
np.random.seed(123)
nums = np.round(np.random.random(size = (3,9)),2)

visitor = pd.DataFrame(nums, index = (100,101,102))
visitor.columns = col_names

group = pd.DataFrame({'item':sorted(items),
                      'family':sorted(['a1','a2','a3']*4)})
```

```
print(visitor)

       2     7     9     10    11    13    14    21    24
100  0.70  0.29  0.23  0.55  0.72  0.42  0.98  0.68  0.48
101  0.39  0.34  0.73  0.44  0.06  0.40  0.74  0.18  0.18
102  0.53  0.53  0.63  0.85  0.72  0.61  0.72  0.32  0.36
```

```
print(group)

    item family
0      2     a1
1      7     a1
2      9     a1
3     10     a1
4     11     a2
5     12     a2
6     13     a2
7     14     a2
8     21     a3
9     22     a3
10    23     a3
11    24     a3
```

The goal is to select top 2 items that are from **DIFFERENT** item-family based on the values. This is my code

```
def Basket(df, x, num_items = 2):
    keys = list(df)   
    values = df.loc[x]   
    item_dict = dict([(i, j) for i, j in zip(keys, values)])
    output = list(dict(sorted(item_dict.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1], reverse = True)))[:num_items]
    return output

print(Basket(df = visitor, dx = 100))
[14, 11]  # 14 & 11 from the same family: a2

print(Basket(df = visitor, x = 101))
[14, 9] # 14 & 9 from different families: a2 & a1
```

I am not sure how to incorporate the **group** df into my code to select top 2 items (based on the values and item-family information) from different family such as

```
print(Basket(df1 = visitor, df2 = group, x = 100))
[14, 2]

print(Basket(df1 = visitor, df2 = group, x = 101))
[14, 9]
```

**Note:** 100, 101, and 102 represent visitor id (row index). any suggestion? many thanks in advance

Comment: What does dx=100 and/or x=101 do?

Comment: 100 & 101 represent visitor id

Comment: When I read the @ScottBoston answer, I think I missed something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
def basket(visitor, x, number_items=2):
    return (visitor.loc[[x]].T                     # selecting visitor id and transposing 
                  .merge(group, 
                         left_index=True, 
                         right_on='item')          # merging with group dataframe 
                  .sort_values(x, ascending=False) # sorting on values in group
                  .groupby('family')               # creating family groups
                  .head(1)                         # selecting one item from each group
                  .head(number_items)['item']      # Getting top n items
                  .to_numpy())                     # return numpy array
```

Output:

```
basket(visitor, 100, 2)
# array([14,  2], dtype=int64)

basket(visitor, 101, 2)
# array([14,  9], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Your approach seems to be very interesting and work. I will definitely give it a try. many thanks

Comment: WoW!!! your code is exactly what I need. Thank you so much.

Comment: @DaCard You're welcome.  Happy coding, be safe and stay healthy.

Answer (score 1):

You can merge your 2 dataframes before:

```
out = visitor.rename_axis('visitor').melt(var_name='item', ignore_index=False) \
             .reset_index().merge(group, on='item')

out = out.loc[out.groupby(['visitor', 'family'])['value'].nlargest(2).index.levels[-1]] \
         .sort_values(['visitor', 'family', 'value'], ascending=[True, True, False], ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
    visitor  item  value family
0       100     2   0.70     a1
1       100    10   0.55     a1
2       100    14   0.98     a2
3       100    11   0.72     a2
4       100    21   0.68     a3
5       100    24   0.48     a3
6       101     9   0.73     a1
7       101    10   0.44     a1
8       101    14   0.74     a2
9       101    13   0.40     a2
10      101    21   0.18     a3
11      101    24   0.18     a3
12      102    10   0.85     a1
13      102     9   0.63     a1
14      102    11   0.72     a2
15      102    14   0.72     a2
16      102    24   0.36     a3
17      102    21   0.32     a3
```

Intermediate result after `merge`:

```
>>> out
    visitor  item  value family
0       100     2   0.70     a1
1       101     2   0.39     a1
2       102     2   0.53     a1
3       100     7   0.29     a1
4       101     7   0.34     a1
5       102     7   0.53     a1
6       100     9   0.23     a1
7       101     9   0.73     a1
8       102     9   0.63     a1
9       100    10   0.55     a1
10      101    10   0.44     a1
11      102    10   0.85     a1
12      100    11   0.72     a2
13      101    11   0.06     a2
14      102    11   0.72     a2
15      100    13   0.42     a2
16      101    13   0.40     a2
17      102    13   0.61     a2
18      100    14   0.98     a2
19      101    14   0.74     a2
20      102    14   0.72     a2
21      100    21   0.68     a3
22      101    21   0.18     a3
23      102    21   0.32     a3
24      100    24   0.48     a3
25      101    24   0.18     a3
26      102    24   0.36     a3
```